# AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT stopped sending the selection object after upgraded Forge Viewer from v6* to v7*

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I was using Basic application viewer V6 and upgraded to V7 with legacy ViewingApplication and everything is working fine except `AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT` didn't send selections while I am selecting an object from Model Browser. It was working fine with V6.

Comment: Even selecting an object from Model browser, Object is not highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

By default the model browser doesn't select a component - it only manages their visibility (or clears your current selection)...

You can however customize the click behavior if necessary with:

```
NOP_VIEWER.modelstructure.clickConfig.click.onObject=['toggleMultipleOverlayedSelection']
```

Or by default you can hold shift and click in the model browser to toggle selection.

And unfortunately I was unable to reproduce the issue with v7.6 when selection is indeed triggered:
[image]

```
NOP_VIEWER.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, e=>console.log(e))

\\ VM274:1 {type: "aggregateSelection", selections: Array(1), target: C}
```

Did you load more than one models? `AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT` only captures selection when we have multiple models loaded.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes, I am loading multiple models. Let me try your solution and will get back to you.